# Shortening the About Url in MVC 5

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-mvc-routing

I am trying to shorten the About and Contact Urls in a new MVC 5 project. Everything I have tried does not work.

```
  routes.MapRoute("ShortAbout", "About", New With {.controller = "Home", .action = "About"})


  routes.MapRoute("ShortenUrl", "{action}", New With {.controller = "Home", .action =       `"Index", .id = UrlParameter.Optional}, New With {.action = "About|Contact"})`
```

What am I missing? I know this has to be simple. I want to get a url like `http://mysite/About` instead of /home/About.

```
   Shared Sub RegisterRoutes(ByVal routes As RouteCollection)
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}")

    routes.MapRoute("ShortAbout", "About", New With {.controller = "Home", .action = "About"})


    routes.MapRoute("ShortenUrl", "{action}", New With {.controller = "Home", .action = "Index", .id = UrlParameter.Optional}, New With {.action = "About|Contact"})


End Sub
```

Comment: Can you post RegisterRoutes() full code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing `RegisterRoutes()` method as below;

```
Public Shared Sub RegisterRoutes(ByVal routes As RouteCollection)
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}")

    routes.MapRoute(
        "ContactRoute",
        "Contact",
        New With {.controller = "Home", .action = "Contact"}
    )

    routes.MapRoute(
        "AboutRoute",
        "About",
        New With {.controller = "Home", .action = "About"}
    )

    routes.MapRoute( _
        name:="Default", _
        url:="{controller}/{action}/{id}", _
        defaults:=New With {.controller = "Home", .action = "Index", .id = UrlParameter.Optional} _
    )
End Sub
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this (C#).

```
routes.MapRoute(
            name: "About",
            url: "About",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "About", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

And make sure it goes before default route.